# Margin auto when using Float element

Tags: html, css, centering, floating

I am trying to build a responsive website using float left and center one of the containers, I am trying to use margin auto but it seems to not do anything.

Can you please guide me how to do that in a responsive way?

I know there might be smarter solutions than using float, but I am trying to learn more about the float element.

```
        <style>
    * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0px;
     }

     html, body {
     height: 100%;
     }

     header {
        height: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-style: solid;
     }
     nav {
        width: 40%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
     }

     .navbar {
        float: right;
     }

     .part1 {
        width: 40%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        margin:  auto;
        float: left;
     }

     .whole {

     }

     main {
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
     }

     footer {
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
     }
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar">
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main class="whole">
            <div class="part1">
            </div>
            <div class="part1">
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
```

Thank you

Comment: Tip: `flex` has rendered most use-cases of `float` obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0px;
     }

     html, body {
     height: 100%;
     }

     header {
        height: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        border-style: solid;
     }
     nav {
        width: 40%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
     }

     .navbar {
        float: right;
     }

     .part1 {
        width: 40%;
        height: 80%;
        border-style: solid;
        margin:  auto;
        float: left;
     }

     .whole {
      display:flex;
     }

     main {
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
     }

     footer {
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20%;
     }
```

```html
 <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar">
            </nav>
        </header>
        <main class="whole">
            <div class="part1">
            </div>
            <div class="part1">
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
```